# RabbitMQ's default consumer thread value?

Tags: rabbitmq, executorservice

I referred the RabbitMQ's documentation for consumer thread pool - [Consumer Thread Pool](https://www.rabbitmq.com/api-guide.html#consumer-thread-pool)

which states

> the default allocation(for consumer thread limit) is more than sufficient.

But what is the maximum number of threads allowed?

Also, just above the code snippet on the link, it states

> Here is an example where a larger thread pool is supplied than is normally allocated.

Does that mean the count is less than 20?

While running my code, the maximum thread count I have seen from logs is 19 (for like 1000 msgs/sec). But I could see lots of messages queued in rabbitMQ client.

Any insights?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend comparing your code's performance with the [PerfTest tool](https://www.rabbitmq.com/java-tools.html#throughput-load-testing) that the RabbitMQ team maintains. If you see greater performance using that then the issue lies with your application.

The code for PerfTest is a good example of how to write a high-performance RabbitMQ publisher and consumer in Java.